# Show photo taken from one activity to another in gridView

Tags: android, gridview

this is my code to send photo to the next activity. Now how do i show the photo's taken in GridView in the receiving activity.

Send:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!imageTaken){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You've not taken any image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Intent iSecond=new Intent(getActivity(),ShowImage.class);
            iSecond.putExtra("pictureUri", imageUri.toString());
            startActivity(iSecond);
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Launching Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            if(imagesFolder.mkdirs()){
                Log.d(TAG, "The directory is created");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed or already exists");
            }
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
            try {
                if(image.createNewFile()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "The file is created");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "The file already exists");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "createNewFile Failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        imageTaken = true;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The image was taken",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Receiving Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);

    grid.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("pictureUri")));
}
```

XML for the Receiving Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RelativeGridLayout"
    >


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

you can't set the image directly to GridView like you are doing. You have to create custom adapter.

For custom adapter you need to first create the layout of the GridView item (which in your case is and ImageView).

After that, pass the (number of) image URIs or URLs to Adapter and set the adapter to the GridView.

May be [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter#) link can give you the hint.